Migrate Domain Controllers
I have two Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controllers DC1 and DC2. I need to migrate both servers to Windows Server 2022.
How it is possible to achieve this while keeping the same IP Addresses and the same names?
Can you provide me a step by step?
Regards

Why do you want to keep same IPs and names?

What research have you done before posting this question?

As you can see from this link, you can upgrade these servers by stepping through Windows Server 2019. It also looks like if you wait until later in the year, you may be able to upgrade directly from 2012R2 to Windows Server 2025.
I have upgraded DCs in the past and I have not had problems. A good backup would be advisable.
Note that if you do choose to install new servers you can easily re-use the same IP addresses if other servers are hard-coded to use the IP addresses for DNS.

Create new domain controllers with WS2022. Move the FSMO roles to the new DCs and then change the IP addresses (WS2022 get the designated IPs) and then remove the old DCs from the domain
